# Can javac infer the right generics for using x.getClass() and x together?

Tags: java, generics

I'd like to have a generic method that takes in an object of some type T, and also a Class representing that type. Eventually I plan to use this to create a `Map<Class<?>, Object>`, where I know that each class will map to an object of exactly its own type; I know I won't be able to convince the compiler of this, but I'd like to keep compile-time generic safety for as much of the code as I can. Here's a minimal example demonstrating the problem I'm running into:

```
public class Example {
  public static <T extends Number> void foo(Class<T> c, T x) {
    ;
  }

  public static void bar(int x) {
    foo(Integer.class, x);
  }

  public static void baz(Number x) {
    foo(x.getClass(), x);
  }
}
```

I can write the `foo` method with no problem, and it has the signature I want, and I can use it if I know exactly what types I have at compile time, as in `bar`, but I can't use it on objects of any type, as I try to in `baz`: `baz` does not compile, citing:

```
Example.java:11: error: method foo in class Example cannot be applied to given types;
    foo(x.getClass(), x);
    ^
  required: Class<T>,T
  found: Class<CAP#1>,Number
  reason: inferred type does not conform to lower bound(s)
    inferred: CAP#1
    lower bound(s): Number
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Number declared in method <T>foo(Class<T>,T)
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Number from capture of ? extends Number
```

I think I understand the problem here: `x.getClass()` returns `Class<? extends Number>`, which establishes `<? extends Number>` as `T`, but `x` continues to have type `Number`, requiring `T` to be `Number`, thus the conflict. When I wrote this, I was hoping that the compiler would know that `x.getClass()` and `x` do share exactly the same `T`, but it makes sense that it can't know that.

So, what do I do here? Is there a way I can write something like `foo` and also something like `baz`? Should I abandon compile-time safety and do some casts at runtime? Is there a better way altogether to approach my end goal of `Map<Class, Object>`?

Comment: `bar(int x)`, why isn't it `bar(Number x)?`

Comment: This can compile if `foo`'s first parameter changes from `Class<T>` to `Class<? extends T>`.

Comment: @rgettman But that allows other things that I *don't* want to allow. Remember my goal is to enforce that the class and the object are the same; I don't want to allow you to store an object reference as the val with its superclass as the key, or with one of its subclasses as the key.

Comment: @amalloy: You can't check that at compile-time at all, though; remember, a reference can always take an instance of a subclass of its declared type. The compiler cannot check for you that the concrete type of `x` is not a subtype of whatever type you declare `x` to be of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation for `Object.getClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass--):

> The actual result type is `Class<? extends |X|>` where `|X|` is the erasure of the static type of the expression on which `getClass` is called.

Note the part about "the erasure of the static type". That means that, if you have a type variable `T` declared, for instance, as `<T extends Number>`, and a variable `T x`, then the return value of `x.getClass()` is not `Class<? extends T>`, but `Class<? extends Number>`. That does indeed make it difficult to do what you want to do without any unsafe casts (admittedly, depending on exactly what it is that you want to do).

However, you can contain the unsafety to its own function. For example, this works:

```
public class test {
    public static <T extends Number> void foo(Class<T> c, T x) {
        ;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> Class<? extends T> getClass2(T x) {
        return((Class<? extends T>)x.getClass());
    }

    public static void bar(int x) {
        foo(Integer.class, x);
    }

    public static void baz(Number x) {
        foo(getClass2(x), x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do this?

```
public static class Example {
    public static <T extends Number> void foo(Class<? extends T> c, T x) {
        ;
    }

    public static void bar(int x) {
        foo(Integer.class, x);
    }

    public static void baz(Number x) {
        foo(x.getClass(), x);
    }
}
```

If you're deadset on maintaining the `foo` signature as `foo(Class<T> c, T x)`, `baz` will have to change as follows:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T extends Number> void baz(T x) {
   foo((Class<T>)x.getClass(), x);
}
```